# GCC: --whole-archive recipe for static linking to pthread stopped working in recent gcc versions

Tags: c++, gcc, pthreads, static-linking

Static linking against pthread is a difficult topic on Linux. It used to work to wrap `-lpthread` as `-Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive` (the details can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45271521/783510)).

The effect was that symbols (for pthread) were [strong, not weak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol). Since around Ubuntu 18.04 (between gcc 5.4.0 and gcc 7.4.0) that behavior seemed to have changed, and pthread symbols now always end up as weak symbols independent of the `--whole-archive` option.

Because of that, the `-whole-archive` recipe stopped working. The intention of my question is to understand what has changed recently in the toolchain (compiler, linker, standard libray), and what can be done to get the old behavior back.

Example:

```
#include <mutex>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::mutex mutex;
  mutex.lock();
  mutex.unlock();
  return 0;
}
```

In all following examples, the same compilation command was used:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -static simple.cpp  -Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread  -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

Before, when compiling with `-static`, pthread symbols (e.g., `pthread_mutex_lock`) were strong (marked as `T` by [`nm`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm)), but now they are weak (`W`):

Ubuntu 14.04: `docker run --rm -it ubuntu:14.04 bash`

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install g++

$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4

$ nm a.out | grep pthread_mutex_lock
0000000000408160 T __pthread_mutex_lock
00000000004003e0 t __pthread_mutex_lock_full
0000000000408160 T pthread_mutex_lock
```

Ubuntu 16.04: `docker run --rm -it ubuntu:16.04 bash`

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609

$ nm a.out | grep pthread_mutex_lock
00000000004077b0 T __pthread_mutex_lock
0000000000407170 t __pthread_mutex_lock_full
00000000004077b0 T pthread_mutex_lock
```

Ubuntu 18.04: `docker run --rm -it ubuntu:18.04 bash`

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0

$ nm ./a.out  | grep pthread_mutex_lock
0000000000407010 T __pthread_mutex_lock
00000000004069d0 t __pthread_mutex_lock_full
0000000000407010 W pthread_mutex_lock
```

To sum it up:

- Ubuntu 14.04 & 16.04: `T pthread_mutex_lock` (strong symbol)
- Ubuntu 18.04: `W pthread_mutex_lock` (weak symbol)

In a more complex example, this can lead to Segmentation faults. For example, in this code (the unmodified file can be found [here](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/4aff114c4c654014a97ef23b1513dda5409e79f3/userland/cpp/thread_get_id.cpp)):

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <thread>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

std::mutex mutex;

void myfunc(int i) {
    mutex.lock();
    std::cout << i << " " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl << std::flush;
    mutex.unlock();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout << "main " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    unsigned int nthreads;

    if (argc > 1) {
        nthreads = std::strtoll(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    } else {
        nthreads = 1;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(myfunc, i));
    }
    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

Attempts to produce a static binary failed, for example:

```
$ g++ thread_get_id.cpp -Wall -std=c++11 -O3 -static -pthread -Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive
$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried to drop `-O3`, switching to `clang++`, switch to the Gold linker, etc. But it always crashes. From my understanding the reason for the crashes in the static binary is that essential functions (such as `pthread_mutex_lock`) do not end up as strong symbols. Thus, they are missing in the final binary, leading to runtime errors.

Apart from Ubuntu 18.04, I could also reproduce the same behavior on Arch Linux with gcc 10.0.0.
However, on Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04, the static binaries could be created and executed without any errors.

**Questions:**

- What changed in the build toolchain (between gcc 5.4.0 and gcc 7.4.0)? (Wild guess: I saw a [pthread cleanup for C11](https://gitlab.com/freedesktop-sdk/mirrors/glibc/commit/fa872e1b6210e81e60d6029429f0a083b8eab26e?w=1) that falls in that time. Maybe that is the reason?)
- Is it a regression, or is the old workaround no longer correct.
- If it is no regression, what should be done instead to allow static linking to pthread?

Comment: Adding `-lrt` after `-lpthread` seems to be enough to avoid the segmentation fault, but I've not yet understood why.

Comment: @Federico Confirmed. With `-lrt` the crash cannot be reproduced. I'm also not sure why it was not needed before. librt is the real-time extensions library (www.mnis.fr/ocera_support/rtos/c1150.html). It seems to be needed by pthread for timing operations like nanosleep. Maybe it was before that implicitly included. Although glibc had librt-related changed during that time. I also read that in other examples, it seems to be necessary to swap the order (`-lpthread` before `-lrt`).

Comment: You can look at my question, The same error solved:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65335620/terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-stdsystem-error/65348893#65348893

Answer (score 6, accepted):

New workaround: `-Wl,--whole-archive -lrt -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive`

---

As pointed out by Federico, adding `-lrt` prevents the crash. The whole issue is almost certainly related to librt, which is the Realtime Extensions library. Its timing functions (e.g., `clock_gettime`, `clock_nanosleep`) are used to implement threads.

Between Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04, there were changes in glibc related to these functions as well. I could not figure out the details, but there are comments in the code:

> /* clock_nanosleep moved to libc in version 2.17;
>       old binaries may expect the symbol version it had in librt.  */

Also for a newer commit message:

> commit 79a547b162657b3fa34d31917cc29f0e7af19e4c 
>   Author: Adhemerval Zanella  
>   Date:   Tue Nov 5 19:59:36 2019 +0000
>
> nptl: Move nanosleep implementation to libc
>
> Checked on x86_64-linux-gnu and powerpc64le-linux-gnu.  I also checked
>       the libpthread.so .gnu.version_d entries for every ABI affected and
>       all of them contains the required versions (including for architectures
>       which exports __nanosleep with a different version).

To sum it up, the workaround is to add `-lrt`. Note that in some examples (not here), the ordering is relevant. From the tests in gcc and some other discussion, I got the impression that first linking against librt causes less problems then linking after pthread. (In one example, only `-lpthread -lrt -lpthread` seemed to have worked, but it is not clear why.)

Comment: Hi, could you add your gcc/g++ version to your answer? It would be more helpful if we can see the version. And who knows what may comes in the next gcc version?

Comment: @Z-Y00 The compiler version can be found in the question (gcc 7.4.0 on Ubuntu 18.04, and gcc 10 on Arch), but I believe the regression was introduced when the system libraries (glibc) changed. I don't think, the compiler version makes a big difference.