# using std::thread in shared library causes SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, stdthread

I just came to Linux c++ programming from Windows. Trying to make a shared library *libso.so*,  which uses `std::thread`. The shared library will be loaded by other people and call the export function. The test code:

```
// so.cpp, the .so library

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

extern "C" 
void run() {
    cout << "run() begin" << endl;

    std::thread t([] {
    });
    t.join();

    cout << "run() end" << endl;
}
```

```
// test.cpp, the test loader

#include <dlfcn.h>

int main() {
    typedef void (*run_t)();

    auto dll = dlopen("libso.so", RTLD_LAZY);

    run_t run = (run_t) dlsym(dll, "run");

    run();
}
```

```
// The CMakeLists.txt file 

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
PROJECT (test)

Include_Directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

Link_Directories(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})

add_library(so SHARED so.cpp )
target_link_libraries(so pthread)

add_executable( test test.cpp )
target_link_libraries(test pthread dl)
```

It crashes in the `run()` function, the output is:

```
run() begin
“./test” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

The `std::thread` seems work fine in executable, but not in shared library. What do I miss?

The environment: g++ 9.3.0, cmake 3.16.3

**Edited:**

**Try ldd.**

`ldd ./test` shows no `pthread`, but `ldd ./libso.so` has `libpthread.so.0`.
The difference of linking param with  `SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE TRUE)`

```
// linking executable 'test'
/usr/bin/c++    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o  -o test   -L/e/c/1/kali  -Wl,-rpath,/e/c/1/kali -ldl -lpthread

// linking library 'libso.so'
/usr/bin/c++ -fPIC   -shared -Wl,-soname,libso.so -o libso.so CMakeFiles/so.dir/so.cpp.o   -L/e/c/2/kali  -Wl,-rpath,/e/c/1/kali -lpthread
```

The only difference is `-fPIC`, I googled and add `set_property(TARGET test PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)` to the executable, but nothing changed.

**Workaround 1**

Since the .so has `libpthread.so.0`, I tried to add the code in .so to the executable:

```
int main() {
    std::thread t([]{}); // to make executable linking to `pthread`
    t.join();

    // ... load dll and call run function
}
```

And it works, now the `ldd ./test` shows `libpthread.so.0` and no crash. Which means: if a shared library uses `std::thread` and an executable wants to load it, the executable itself must also use `std::thread`.

**Workaround 2**:

The `std::thread` works fine in executable, but crashes in shared library. Found some [related discuss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58848694/gcc-whole-archive-recipe-for-static-linking-to-pthread-stopped-working-in-rec), the **walkaround** is using `boost::thread` instead of `std::thread` and linking to `boost_thread` library, no crash .

Comment: May be you should test whether `dll` or `run` is not null before using it?

Comment: They are not null, I removed the error check to simplify the code, the output `run() begin` comfirms  function `run` called correctly.

Comment: Off: I think it would work if you used `C` and `pthreads`. (Of course you would have to build both the main program and the plugin with `-pthread` option.)

Comment: @aj3423 I think I have found the cause of this weird behaviour, and a fix in the build process to prevent it from happening. (see the second edit in my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem is more related to dynamic linking
than threads.

The call `dlopen("libso.so", RTLD_LAZY)` will try to
find the library in a standard location.
Except if you set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment
variable to something that includes `.` (the current
directory) this library won't be found.

For a simple test you can either:

- use `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` in the terminal before
  launching your program,
- use `dlopen("./libso.so", RTLD_LAZY)` in your source code.

After using `dlopen()` or `dlsym()` if you obtain a null
pointer, then `dlerror()` can help displaying the reason
of the failure.

Note that on Windows the current directory and the executable
path are standard search paths for dynamic libraries; on UNIX
this is not the case, which could be surprising when changing
the target platform.

---

**edit**

`cmake` uses the `-Wl,-rpath` option to hardcode a library search
path in the executable, so all of what I explained above becomes
useless for this problem.

Assuming the dynamic library is found, the only way I can reproduce
the crash is to *forget* `pthread` in `target_link_libraries` for
`test`.

---

**second edit**

I finally managed to reproduce the crash with Ubuntu (in WSL).
Apparently your linker decides to ignore the libraries that are
not directly used by the executable.
This behavior suggests that the linker option `--as-needed` is
switched on by default.
To contradict this default behaviour, you need to pass the linker
option `--no-as-needed` **before** `-lpthread`.
This way, you don't have to insert a *dummy* thread in your
executable.
Using `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -Wl,--no-as-needed)` in the `CMakeLists.txt`
file you provide did the trick for me.

Comment: I tried both `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ` and `dlopen("./libso.so", RTLD_LAZY)`, still crashes.

Comment: @aj3423 my bad, see the edit, sorry to have been so misleading :-( . But your example works perfectly for me, I cannot reproduce the crash without modifying `CMakeLists.txt`. (g++ 9.3.0, cmake 3.17.1)

Comment: The `boost::thread` works, maybe the implement of `std::thread` and `boost::thread` is different. Post updated.

Comment: @aj3423 and did you try to link your executable against `rt` *before* `pthread` as mentioned in the link of your update? Even without cmake (a simple makefile to enable a better control of the build options) the only way to reproduce the crash (I tried on different linux systems) is to *forget* to link the executable against `pthread`. When you run `ldd ./test` can you see that `libpthread.so` is actually found?

Comment: I tried the `rt` before `pthread`, and after, and before+after, still crash. I added the detailed linking param and `ldd` output to the post.

Comment: cmake uses `/usr/bin/c++`, which is just a symbol link to `/usr/bin/g++`, `g++ --version` is *g++ (Debian 9.3.0-10) 9.3.0*. I'm running on Kali linux with everything up to date.   And the `std::this_thread::get_id();` also crashes, there must be an instance of `std::thread`, otherwise it will crash.

Comment: That's it, the default `--as-need` causes the problem. With `target_link_libraries(test dl "-Wl,--no-as-needed" pthread "-Wl,--as-needed")` in cmake, now works fine. Thank you.