# Is there a bug in GCC 7.3.0 link thread library use -static?

Tags: c++, c++11, pthreads, std, gcc7

I use std::call_once in my code, it compiled succeed but crashed when runing...
like this demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;
    static once_flag of;
    call_once(of,[]{});
    cout << "see you again" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Later I found,if i compiled with -static,it crashed,but run succeed just with -pthread or -lpthread:
[image]

Comment: You could easily have edited your original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65335620) as you were advised to do, by simply adding the image. I'm quite confused by why you've posted a new question. It looks like more effort for no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

`std::call_once` is implemented in libstdc++ on Linux using [`pthread_once`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_once.3p.html). So you have to link with the pthread library to get its definition. [See this thread for details](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60662#c2). That's why `-pthread` becomes necessary. You can also see that using [`nm`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html) or [`objdump`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html).

To be able to statically link pthread library, you need to ensure the all objects are linked in your binary. [See this thread for details](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52590).
Instead, you can include the whole archive with:

```
g++ std_callonce.cpp -g -static -Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

That should work as you want.

But note that, though there are some rare cases where static linking is useful, it's generally [considered harmful](https://akkadia.org/drepper/no_static_linking.html).

Comment: The bug report you linked is from 2012.  I suppose I can respect their decision not to make `-static` work without further options, but I'm surprised they haven't at least documented it (as far as I can tell).  Static linking seems like a fairly natural thing to want to do when appropriate, despite its tradeoffs, and the workaround isn't at all obvious.

Comment: I had try -Wl,--whole-archive -lrt -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive, I it worked on my Ubuntu-16.04, but still crashed on my embedded Linux.
A good news, I got a useful fix,in my another questiom:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65335620/terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-stdsystem-error/65348893#65348893