# Why is std::thread::join segfaulting here?

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads

Okay, I encountered this problem before 10 minutes. Below is a code snippet, which SEGFAULTs right at the `join()` statement, without any particular reason. As far I'm concerned the code is correct (I had the same problem at a large server application, so I copy-pasted this working snippet from the internet):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main() {
    std::thread t([]() {
        std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
        std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    });
    std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    t.join();
    std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What exactly is wrong here?
Compiled with...

```
u@p:~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

...by...

```
g++ main.cpp -lpthread
```

Comment: If you replace `-lpthread` with `-pthread`does it still segfault?

Comment: No, but... Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling

Comment: Okay, I get it. Now is the question: Why does is not work again, when I use `-static` additionally?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116327/when-g-static-link-pthread-cause-segmentation-fault-why

Comment: @Simonmicro The `g++` command doesn't support POSIX threads on Linux. You need to use `g++ -pthread` on Linux if you want POSIX threads support.