# segmentation fault using static libraries with std::jthread (g++-10)

Tags: c++, static-libraries, c++20

I'm developing a library that works with `std::jthread` (new in C++20) using g++ 10.0.1. The library works fine if I compile it using share libraries, but If I compile it with static libraries I got a segmentation fault at the end of the program (thread destructor). I have narrowed down my test case to a simple thread creation and join:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
  auto t = std::jthread([]() { std::cout << "OK\n"; });
  t.join();
  return 0;
}
```

To compile I use:

```
g++-10 -o test --static -std=c++20 test.cc -lpthread
```

And running it:

```
% ./test
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./test
```

There any one has an idea what this problem could be?

**Update:**

Following @JérômeRichard suggested reference, I was able to compile and run my little test program without problem

```
g++-10 -o test --static -std=c++20 test.cc -lrt -pthread  -Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

However, changing the code to use `request_stop` instead of `join` the program is segmenting fault again (https://godbolt.org/z/obGN8Y).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main() {
    auto t = std::jthread([]{ std::cout << "OK" << std::endl; });
    t.request_stop();
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `-lpthread` with `-pthread`. That's what you should always use anyway. Edit: That doesn't seem to help: https://godbolt.org/z/y_Fg2P

Comment: It seems the issue is related to the `--static`: without, no segmentation faults are reported. Note that a similar problem also appear with the regular `std::thread` on older version of GCC (eg. GCC 9) and without the `-std=c++20`.

Comment: It is apparently related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116327/when-g-static-link-pthread-cause-segmentation-fault-why !

Comment: As an aside, calling own programs `test`  is confusing.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I should think that the answer there will solve this problem as well. Curious whether it will work for the OP here. Btw, the most upvoted answer there is an interesting lecture on the inner workings of glibc and the linker, static vs. dynamic linking and weak/strong symbols.

Comment: `request_stop` is inappropriate to call unless you are cooperatively cancelling the thread. `join()` is proper here. That said, it appears to work with the latest version of gcc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was reported to libstdc++ (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95989) and a patch has been generated to solve the problem.