# c++ segfault before main gtest

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm getting a stacktrace before main:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

stacktrace:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

```
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000004e0b51 in std::locale::_S_initialize() ()
#2  0x00000000004e0b93 in std::locale::locale() ()
#3  0x000000000050d524 in std::ios_base::Init::Init() ()
#4  0x0000000000401581 in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (__initialize_p=1, __priority=65535) at /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:74
#5  0x00000000004015b3 in _GLOBAL__sub_I_testsmain.cpp(void) () at ../../../bdf_cpp_tests/testsmain.cpp:18
#6  0x000000000053cdd7 in __libc_csu_init ()
#7  0x000000000053c3de in generic_start_main ()
#8  0x000000000053c62a in __libc_start_main ()
#9  0x00000000004013f9 in _start ()
```

This is qmake 5.7 and g++ 4.9.4

I believe this is the command that runs:

```
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -std=gnu++11 -std=c++11 -Werror -pedantic -DTEST_RESOURCE_DIR=\"/home/eric/Documents/BDFCppLib/test_resources\" -DTEST_OUTPUT_DIR=\"/home/eric/Documents/BDFCppLib/test_resources/output\" -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -fPIC -DDEBUG -I../../../bdf_cpp_tests -I/home/eric/Documents/BDFCppLib/shadow-ant/ubuntu64_gcc49_dev/bdf_cpp_tests -I../../../bdf_cpp_sdk/include -I../../../lib/ubuntu64_gcc49_dev/unpack/chunk_cpp/include -I../../../lib/ubuntu64_gcc49_dev/unpack/system/include -I/home/eric/Software/qt/5.7/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o testsmain.o ../../../bdf_cpp_tests/testsmain.cpp

g++  -o ../../../build/ubuntu64_gcc49_dev/bin/bdf_cpp_run_tests testsmain.o testutils.o   -pthread -lrt -L/home/eric/Documents/BDFCppLib/build/ubuntu64_gcc49_dev/lib -static -lbdf -L/home/eric/Documents/BDFCppLib/lib/ubuntu64_gcc49_dev/unpack/chunk_cpp/lib -static -lchunk -L/home/eric/Documents/BDFCppLib/lib/ubuntu64_gcc49_dev/unpack/system/lib -lgtest
```

UPDATE 0:
I'm running into this issue on Ubuntu 16.04.  I created a VM with 14.04, copied the code over and everything worked.  No segfault.  So something is different about 16.04 that seems to be causing this.

UPDATE 1:
I'm starting to think this is being caused by googletest.  I don't know why it would work with 14.04 and not 16.06.  Anything that includes and uses google test will not be able to run because of an immediate segfault.

Comment: what does your qmake file look like?

Comment: "I believe this is the command that runs" It's certainly not the command that runs to link your crashing gtest program. [mcve] needed.

Comment: Just added the other line, does that help?

Comment: I think this is very similar to this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786161/why-does-linking-with-pthread-cause-a-segmentation-fault, but I could not find the root cause in my case

Answer (score 5):

Why are you using `gcc` ? It's better to use `g++`. The above code when compiled using `g++`, generates no error, and when run, prints the value of `argc` to be 1, and `argv` to be some random address, since no command line argument is provided.

`__static_initialization_and_destruction_0` occurs because of `gcc`. `gcc` creates a `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0` for every translation unit that needs static constructors to be called. Then it places `__do_global_ctors_aux` into the `.ctors` section, which then calls `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0` on each translation unit.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is using g++, i mis-typed.  I'm adding the line that runs to my question.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using Cmake + [Conan](https://conan.io/) and linked every library statically.
I've had `pthreads` as a last dependency for Google Test.
I've applied solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116327/when-g-static-link-pthread-cause-segmentation-fault-why) to link `pthreads` with `--whole-archive` flag.

Example for Cmake (see [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/target_link_libraries.html)):

```
target_link_libraries(my_app gtest_main gtest -Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
```

After that it worked.