# aarch64 gdb debug libstdc++ could not find method stringstream str()

Tags: c++, arm64

I have alreay installed the libstdc++-debuginfo package in Fedora21-aarch64,but when use the gdb to print the stringstream.str(), I always got this message:

```
(gdb) ptype sp
type = class std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::basic_stringstream<char,   std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >
[with _Tp = std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >]
    : public std::tr1::__shared_ptr<std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> {
public:
shared_ptr(void);
void shared_ptr<std::basic_stringstream<char> >(std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > *);
}
(gdb) p sp->str()
 Couldn't find method std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::str
```

the source code like below:

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<stringstream> sp ( new stringstream(ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ios_base::binary));
std::tr1::shared_ptr<ostream> osp = sp;
osp->write("hello",6);
cout<<sp->str()<<endl;
```

and the debuginfo package i have installed like below:

```
#debuginfo-install libstdc++
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks
Package gcc-debuginfo-4.9.2-1.fc21.aarch64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-debuginfo-2.20-5.fc21.aarch64 already installed and latest version
Package gcc-debuginfo-4.9.2-1.fc21.aarch64 already installed and latest version
No debuginfo packages available to install
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Similar question which may provide the answer (-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023934/debug-through-libstdc

Comment: @stefaanv Hi,i tried ,but it can't work in my environment.

Comment: No idea what "it fails yet" means.

Comment: @jefby: "it can't work in my environment" is not really helpful for solving your problem.  If it means that you can't compile your code with this flag, then I'm afraid there's not much that can be done.

Comment: @stefaanv Hi stefaanv. I'm sorry for my incorrect describe.I have compiled the source code with the -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG option, but when use the gdb debug ,it results a same error( Couldn't find method std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::str
)

Comment: @stefaanv, `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` has **nothing** to do with debugging in GDB, it adds extra assertions to the code and changes types. Not useful here at all.

Answer (score 0):

In general GDB isn't very good at calling C++ functions when debugging. The problem is that unless the `stringstream::str()` function is actually present in the executable GDB can't call it, and often the function isn't present, either because you didn't use it in your program or it got inlined into all callers.

You could try:

```
p sp->_M_stringbuf.str();
```

or if that still doesn't work then:

```
p sp->_M_stringbuf._M_string._M_dataplus._M_p
```

That will print the `char*` member of the string inside the stringstream's stringbuf.

Comment: Hi, @Jonathan Wakely. I run your command with gdb,but it always get an message like below:
(gdb) p sp->_M_stringbuf._M_string._M_dataplus._M_p
There is no member named _M_stringbuf.
(gdb) p sp->_M_stringbuf.str()
There is no member named _M_stringbuf. I use the gdb7.9.1

Comment: What about `p sp._M_ptr->_M_stringbuf._M_string._M_dataplus._M_p`

Comment: (gdb) p sp._M_ptr->_M_stringbuf._M_string._M_dataplus._M_p
There is no member named _M_stringbuf.

Comment: I have no idea what's going on, that member definitely exists.