# Clion debug: How to step into STL

Tags: c++, debugging, stl, clion

I want to know how string works, so I add breakpoint in basic_string.h.
But it not step into these breakpoint when I debug.

When I add breakpoint in debug time, GDB console show this:
No line 1008 in file "C:/Users/manch/Downloads/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hYmR.png)

This is my test code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string *ps = new std::string("hello");
    ps->append(" world");
    return 0;
}
```

and CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(Stl)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp test.cpp  C:/Users/manch/Downloads/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/bits/stl_construct_copy.h)
add_executable(Stl ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will also need to have the source files for `libstdc++` the standard C++ libraries MinGW links your executable with. Then, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023934/debug-through-libstdc) question, you will need to add the `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` flag upon compilation so that libraries with debug information are linked.